# Session Lifetime Not Working as Expected

Tags: php, session

I set the `gc_max_lifetime` setting in `php.ini` to 7 days in seconds yet for some reason it doesn't work, I logged in yesterday after setting up `php.ini` then came on today and I was logged out.

I see this option:

```
Lifetime in seconds of cookie or, if 0, until browser is restarted.
session.cookie_lifetime = 0;
```

Should I mess with it and what does it mean exactly?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gc_max_lifetime` has nothing to with session cookies. `gc` - garbage collector. it tells php how long dormant session files should be allowed to hang around before getting deleted. It's purely a server-side setting.

You want [session.cookie_lifetime](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) instead.

---

and as per your edit, yes, you've set your session cookies to be `session` cookies - delete on browser close. Set that value to something non-zero. e.g. 86400 = 1 day.

Comment: Oh ok, Excuse my mistake but a lot of tutorials on here state differently. May I ask what a good number is to set for max_lifetime?

Comment: a good lifetime is up to you to decide. e.g. if it's a banking-type site, you want a relatively short lifetime (say, 15 minutes). For something essentially useless, like Farcebook, you could set it to a few million years.

Comment: So gc_max_lifetime simply adds a delay before it dumps sessions that have been idle for x amount of time?

Comment: @ShinyMagikarp something longer than `session.cookie_lifetime` (otherwise it could theoretically be garbage collected before the cookie expires) : *however* you have to bear in mind PHP doesn't automatically refresh the cookie expiry date - set the cookie to expire in 10 minutes and it'll expire in 10 minutes whether the user is actually doing anything on-site or not. The easiest/best time to deal with for a session cookie is `0` (i.e. the session expires when the browser closes, give or take, which is pretty much the definition of a session).

Comment: I see, Like currently im trying to get it to just keep the sessions up for 7 days then delete every session. But after I get this sorted (Using this as default expire date) im going to go and try implement a remember me checkbox. Is there anyway you can show me a documented way on doing so? I have seen many tutorials on how to do this but none of them document there answer on whats happening.

Comment: it's usually not a good idea to use sessions for remember-me type systems. better to store the data elsewhere while "expired" and quickly restore it when the user comes back.